# Get query being fired in graphql spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am making a graphql application using the following implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am also implementing web security(JWT token in the same). If I were to filter out my types of query for login and register to be open. How can i do so? Currently I am using the following:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In filter");
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");    
System.out.println(request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

The output

```
{"query":"# query{\n#   firstQuery\n# }\n\nquery{\n  getuser(username: \"user1\") {\n    username\n    password\n  }\n}","variables":{},"operationName":null}
```

Currently in the security config I am passing everything as a pass:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

This is giving me some results but it requires a lot of manual work post this. Also as you can see it is including comments.
Any idea to so the same in a simpler way. I am willing to change the graphql implementaion if required. I am also quite new to jwt and graphql. Any help is much appreciated.